# Openlayers language encoding problem

Tags: openlayers-2, encoding

I'm trying to change OpenLayers.Lang file to Turkish. I succeeded to some extent except for encoding. when I use şiüçöİı chars that are particular to Turkish, they are replaced with some strange characters.

Is there a way to handle this problem?

Comment: Does your webserver send the proper encoding headers?

Comment: Yes, it is. Excep for openlayers components all is well